# Custom font in UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uisearchbar

i have installed avenir font in x-code for custom font.

and i have tried this code to set custom font to search bar text

```
 UITextField *textField = [[sbOffers subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

 [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:25]];
```

but this is not worked for me i got error.Like this

[image]

is there any solution for this or anyother way to set font for UISearchBar ??  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe your code works fine up to iOS 7.
Since iOS 7, there are some changes in UISearchBar subviews hierarchy.
Here is correct way to get UITextField inside UISearchBar,

```
for (UIView *view in [[yourSearchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField *)view setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:25]];
    }
}
```